# Get the combination of two python functions

Tags: python

I'm writing a game based on a grid pattern where the player can move in all directions. The diagonal directions can be represented as two consecutive moves in a straight direction, e.g. the direction up-left is first up and then left. How could I then return a function that first executes the up-move and then the left-move on the result? Snippet of my current tile class:

```py
class Tile():
    def __init__(self,row,col):
        self.row,self.col = row,col

    def up(self):
        return Tile(self.row+1,self.col)
    def down(self):
        return Tile(self.row-1,self.col)
    def left(self):
        return Tile(self.row,self.col-1)
    def right(self):
        return Tile(self.row,self.col+1)
```

and I have a method that returns all these functions:

```py
def directions():
    return [Tile.up,Tile.down,Tile.left,Tile.right]
```

How do I also add the diagonal functions to this list? I want to return the combined function, something along the lines of `return Tile.up(Tile.left)`

Thank you!

Comment: can't you just do `def upLeft(self): return Tile(self.row+1,self.col-1)` ?

Comment: Try `lambda x : Tile.up(Tile.left(x))`

Comment: Tiles shouldn't be the ones creating new tiles, what would you do to return to a previous tile? You should have something else in control of the map and movement

Comment: Thank you @JhanzaibHumayun, I did not think of that ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `lambda x : Tile.up(Tile.left(x))` worked, so just wanted to leave an explanation here. By using `lambda x : Tile.up(Tile.left(x))` you create an anonymous function on one line. And then you can easily add this function to your list.

```
def directions():
    return [Tile.up,Tile.down,Tile.left,Tile.right, lambda x : Tile.up(Tile.left(x))]
```